# Como obtener el nombre de un archivo y almacenar en un input text?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo en mi formulario el input file en el cual elijo la imagen y su ruta se muestra en mi input text, el problema es que me almacena la ruta con ***C:\fakepath*** y yo lo único que necesito es que me muestre el nombre del archivo y su extensión. ¿Alguna sugerencia para esto?

```js
function actualiza(nombre){ 
  document.getElementById('m1').value='http://localhost:8080/evidencia/'+ nombre; 
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onChange="actualiza(this.value)">
<input type="text" id="m1" value="ruta" class="form-control">
</div>              
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este es un resultado típico que tienen los navegadores por cuestiones de seguridad para que desde JavaScript no sepa la ruta completa del archivo si no que la enmascara en una ruta C:\pakepath , esto está especificado en la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file)  en la sección `value` hay una NOTA con este detalle.

Al acceder al atributo `value`, está accediendo a un String quee representa la ruta al archivo(s) seleccionado(s). Si el usuario seleccionó varios archivos, `value` representa el primer archivo en la lista.

Entonces para obtener el nombre puede obtener los archivos cargados , puede hacerlo con `files` que retornará un `array` y si es solo un archivo seleccionado puede acceder al indice `0` y luego al atributo `name`

```js
function actualiza(nombre){ 
  console.log(nombre);
  document.getElementById('m1').value='http://localhost:8080/evidencia/'+ nombre; 
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera" onChange="actualiza(this.files[0].name)">
<input type="text" id="m1" value="ruta" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Me encorazonas, muchas gracias!